# How to capture exception by SQL Server to console program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

```
for(int i=0; i < fileDirectories.Count;i++){

string script = File.ReadAllText(@fileDirectories[i]);
string[] singleCommand = Regex.Split(script,"^GO", RegexOptions.Multiline);
StringCollection scl = new StringCollection();

foreach(string t in singleCommand){
    if(t.Trim().Length > 0) scl.Add(t.Trim());
}

try
{
    int[] result = Server
               .ConnectionContext
               .ExecuteNonQuery(scl, ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError);
}catch(Exception e)
{
//whatever
}
}
```

The objective of this program is to run multiple scripts and if fail, capture the exceptions thrown by SQL SERVER and continue running the remaining scripts.

In order to try out, INSERT PERMISSION has been taken away from DB and hence first query (INSERT query) will fail when being executed on SQL SERVER manually because `INSERT PERMISSION` been taken away with below Error

`The INSERT permission was denied on object 'xxx',database 'xxxxx', schema 'xx'`

When running the program, variable `result` will have value 0 indicating the query failed but however it's not throwing error and being catch at `catch`? How should I pass the exception given by SQL Server to my console program?

Comment: isn't that error in `e` object?

Comment: The code is not going to `catch` section

Comment: why do you set `ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError`?

Comment: Because the program is expecting to loop 100 queries. Even when in the middle there is something wrong, exceptions thrown by SQL server are to be captured and remaining queries are expected to continue to run

Comment: if you use try catch the loop won't stop either?

Comment: Lei Yang is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(
    string sqlCommand,
    ExecutionTypes executionType
)
```

instead of

```
public int[] ExecuteNonQuery(
    StringCollection sqlCommands,
    ExecutionTypes executionType
)
```

For example

```
foreach (string t in singleCommand)
        {
            if (t.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    // do not use ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError, it will not
                    // throw any exceptions
                    int result = Server
                        .ConnectionContext
                        .ExecuteNonQuery(t, ExecutionTypes.Default); 
                }
                catch (ExecutionFailureException ex) 
                {
                    // do anything
                    // do not throw error here
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // do anything
                    // do not throw error here
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError`.

No exception is thrown when you set execution type to ContinueOnError.

```
try
{
      int[] result = Server.ConnectionContext
                    .ExecuteNonQuery(stringColleciton);
}
catch(SqlException se)
{
      //write log, show message
}
catch(Exception e)
{
      //write log, show message
}
```

Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199301(v=sql.120).aspx) about `ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery Method (String, ExecutionTypes)`

Comment: Please find my question been updated. Thank you for suggestion if any.